# Join two tables in nhibernate mvc c#

Tags: c#, join, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am joining two tables using primary key and foreign key.

My tables are

1. **Item**, Columns are:

   - **ItemId** int primary key,
   - **Name** varchar,
   - **Price** float,
   - **CategoryID** int foreign key,
   - **QtyInStock** int
2. **Category**, Columns are:

   - **Id** int pk,
   - **Category** varchar,
   - **Name** varchar

I want to select Category on basis of ID=categoryId

I am using NHibernate 4.03 with xml configuration files.

Comment: 1. MVC has nothing to do with that. You can remove that tag.
2. This appears to be a rather basic example. What have you tried so far? 
3. Do you want to use QueryOver, Linq, or anything else?

Comment: Are related your entities by mapping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For unrelated entities:

```
var query = from item in session.Query<Item>() 
    join category in session.Query<Category>() on item.CategoryID equals category.Id;
```

For related entities:

```
Category catAlias = null;

var query = session.QueryOver<Item>()
    .JoinAlias(x => x.Category, () => catAlias);
```

Comment: select c.ItemId,c.Name,c.Price,c.QtyInStock,d.Category from Item as c, Category as d where c.CategoryID=d.Id                                                                                          I want this result in output in mvc 5 nhibernate