# NHibernates QueryOver and reverse associations

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

How do I find any `C` classes without references using NHibernate's `QueryOver`?

```
public class A {
    public List<C> c { get; set; }
}

public class B {
    public List<C> c { get; set; }
}

public class C {
}
```

The same in SQL:

```
select C.* from C
left join A on C.Id = A.C
left join B on C.Id = B.C
where A.Id is null and B.Id is null
```

If I had only one join, something like this would work:

```
session.QueryOver<A>(() => a)
    .Right.JoinQueryOver(() => a.C, () => c)
    .WhereRestrictionOn(() => a.DbId)
    .IsNull
    .List() // TODO: use transfomer to select C
```

EDIT: I'm not sure if it matters if the references are `List<C>` or just plain `C`.

Anyway, I'm interested how I could I root the query at `C` and then do joins where I have no direct `path` available

Comment: You should use `session.QueryOver(() => c).Left.JoinAlias(c => c.a, () => a).Left.JoinAlias(c => c.b, () => b)` instead `JoinQueryOver` to evict change the query root, but you need to add `A` and `B` references in `C`.

Comment: @Najera The point is that there is no `c.a` or `c.b`. Only  `A` and `B` have references to `C`, but not the other way round. Thanks though.

Comment: Check if Linq support your query as unrelated entities http://stackoverflow.com/a/29923220/1486443

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems to work, but not the answer I was hoping for:

```
C c = null;
var aSubquery = QueryOver.Of<A>()
    .JoinAlias(a => a.C, () => c)
    .Select(Projections.Property(() => c.Id));
var bSubquery = QueryOver.Of<B>()
    .JoinAlias(b => b.C, () => c)
    .Select(Projections.Property(() => c.Id));
session.QueryOver<C>()
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereProperty(x => x.Id).NotIn(aSubquery)
    .WithSubquery
    .WhereProperty(x => x.Id).NotIn(bSubquery);
```

If you have a better answer, please provide an alternative.